# Convert 9V train to Powered Up

Tags: motor, trains, powered-up

This is a follow-up from question "[Can I convert my train 9V 4563 to the Power Functions motor?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9835/can-i-convert-my-train-9v-4563-to-the-power-functions-motor)", now that *Power Functions* motors have been phased out in favour of *Powered Up* motors.

How can I convert a train locomotive from the 9V system to the Powered Up system?

Let's assume the oldest 9V locomotive, the one from [set 4563-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4563-1).

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, if you place the hub in the closed van and couple the van behind the locomotive. Swapping out the 9v motor for the Powered Up motor is straightforward; you will then need to remove a 1x2 brick from the back of the locomotive cab and a 1x2 panel from the front of the van to allow the wire to pass through.

I would also suggest modifying the van roof so that it is easier to reach the power switch on the hub.[image: Part-disassembly of locomotive and van showing cable routing]

Adding lighting using 88005 is left as an exercise for the interested reader.

Comment: That's neat! Would it be possible to place the cable further down, closer to the couplings, in order to hide it a bit?

Comment: I think you could replace the rear light prism brick with a couple of headlamp bricks and run the cable between them, if you wanted it at that height.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's assume the oldest 9V locomotive, the one from set 4563-1.

I don't think you can convert that locomotive without dramitically changing it's appearance.

The basic components of a powered-up locomotive are a train motor and a hub, the train motor is basically the same size/shape as the old 9V track powered motor but the hub is a large additional component to accomodate.

There are a few different hubs, but the one included in the train sets is 4 studs wide. That basically means that either the section of the locomotive where the hub is located ends up at least 6 studs wide, or the sides of the hub and possiblly the connectors plugged into the hub will be visible.

It may be possible to put the hub in a wagon pulled behind the locomotive to try and preserve the appearance of the locomotive, but I expect wire management to be a challange.

Comment: 4563 includes a closed van; it is very likely possible to put the hub in the van and couple the van behind the loco. I have done this with 12v trains of similar dimensions such as 7760 and the diesel-outline alternative build of 7730.